# BinTree.BinaryTree<T> requires 1 type arguments?

Tags: c#, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

**EDIT:**
What's the best way to populate the tree? I'm adding 10 random numbers in at the moment

```
BinTree<int> myTree = new BinTree<int>();
            int Value;

            Console.WriteLine("Inserting Values:  ");
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                Value = random.Next(100);
                Console.Write(Value + " ");

               myTree.node(Value);
            }
```

But

```
> myTree.node(Value);
```

keeps erroring with *"Error 1   'BINTREE.BinTree' does not contain a definition for 'node' and no extension method 'node' accepting a first argument of type 'BINTREE.BinTree' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
"*

```
 class BinTree<T> where T : IComparable
    {
        private NODE<T> root;

        public BinTree()
        {
            root = null;
        }

        public BinTree(NODE<T> node)
        {
            root = node;
        }



//order algorithms
        public void PreOrder()
        {
            PREORDER(root);
        }

        private void PREORDER(NODE<T> tree)                          
        {                                                                
            if (tree != null)
            {
                Console.Write(tree.Data);                              
                PREORDER(tree.Left);                                   
                PREORDER(tree.Right);                                  
            }
        }

        public void PostOrder()
        {
            POSTORDER(root);
        }

        private void POSTORDER(NODE<T> tree)                            
        {                                                                 
            if (tree != null)
            {
                POSTORDER(tree.Left);                                     
                POSTORDER(tree.Right);                                    
                Console.WriteLine(tree.Data);                             
            }
        }

        public void InOrder()
        {
            INORDER(root);
        }

        private void INORDER(NODE<T> tree)                              
        {                                                                 
            if (tree != null)
            {
                INORDER(tree.Left);                                       
                Console.WriteLine(tree.Data);                             
                INORDER(tree.Right);                                      
            }
        }
```

Comment: First of all, you can't call an instance method from the type name.  Second of all, why are you trying to call a private method from outside the class?  What exactly is going on here?

Comment: Technically the call was to a public instance method. In order to call a class method(not an instance), you must instantiate a variable. Or the method/property or whatever you want to use should be static.  In this case if you did call it and it was static, most likely you would get an error/exception because in the public InOrder() method you would be calling a private instance method...but of what instance?

Answer (score 3):

There are several things going on here.
The specific error is because you are referencing the class `BinaryTree` without a generic argument, or that `T` you see in the class' definition.

There are other problems with your code however:

1) You cannot access non-static members without instantiating the class. AKA The class definition doesn't know what data you want to operate on.

2) You are attempting to call the private `inOrder` routine, which is inaccessible. Notice the difference between the lower and uppercase i. You want to call the public `InOrder()`

Your end code should look something like this:

```
BinaryTree<int> myBinaryTree = new BinaryTree<int>();
myBinaryTree.InOrder();
```

However, this code will not work as you have an unpopulated tree (even the root node is null).

**Edit:** By not work I mean no output will be produced. Looking at your class definition for BinaryTree you will need to add ways to populate the tree in order to effectively test the method for printing the tree out.

Answer (score 0):

Because it generic, you have to pass in the type that is used where you see the , the  is the type that is used through the object where the type is important.

Comment: Look at James answer, he provides an example.